# Multiprocessing with renewable queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to figure out how to write a program in python that uses the multiprocessing queue.

I have multiple servers and one of them will provide the queue remotely with this:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import Queue
import daemonme

queue = Queue.Queue()

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

daemonme.createDaemon()
QueueManager.register('get_job', callable=lambda:queue)
m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='')
s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()
```

Now I want to use my dual Xeon, quad core server to process jobs off of this remote queue. The jobs are totally independent of one another. So if I have 8 cores, I'd like to start 7 processes that pick a job off the queue, process it, then go back for the next one. Each of the 7 processes will do this, but I can't quite get my head wrapped around the structure of this program.

Can anyone provide me some educated ideas about the basic structure of this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Look to the doc how to retreive a queue from the [manager](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.managers) (paragraph 17.6.2.7)
than with a [pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.managers) (paragraph 17.6.2.9) of workers launch 7 jobs passing the queue to each one.

in alternative you can think something like a producer/consumer problem:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import random

class Producer():
def __init__(self):
    BaseManager.register('queue')
    self.m = BaseManager(address=('hostname', 50000), authkey='jgsjgfdjs')
    self.m.connect()
    self.cm_queue = self.m.queue()
    while 1:
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
        self.cm_queue.put(<PUT-HERE-JOBS>)

from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time
import random
class Consumer():
def __init__(self):
    BaseManager.register('queue')

    self.m = BaseManager(address=('host', 50000), authkey='jgsjgfdjs')
    self.m.connect()
    self.queue = self.m.queue()
    while 1:
        <EXECUTE(job = self.queue.get())>


from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, Queue
class Manager():

def __init__(self):

    self.queue = QueueQueu()

    BaseManager.register('st_queue', callable=lambda:self.queue)

    self.m = BaseManager(address=('host', 50000), authkey='jgsjgfdjs')
    self.s = self.m.get_server()

    self.s.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I have this working (thank you). What I need to know is in your section <EXECUTE(job = self.queue.get())> what is the best way to process these jobs? They're all python files so would it be best to run them as a module? Or should they be run under a separate python process with the subprocess module?

Comment: look to the OS module and to its exec method for example

Answer (score 0):

You should use the master-slave (aka. farmer-worker) pattern. The initial process would be the master and creates the jobs. It

1. creates a Queue
2. creates 7 slave processes, passing the queue as a parameter
3. starts writing jobs into the queue

The slave processes continuously read from the queue, and perform the jobs (perhaps until they receive a stop message from the queue). There is no need to use Manager objects in this scenario, AFAICT.

Comment: How you implementation would manage *remote* queues? I think multiprocessing.managers is a really good choice if he needs to share resources remotely.